# download openBLAS from SourceForge using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sourceforge, openblas

I would like to use PowerShell to download openBLAS from SourceForge. My problem is that the PS documentation I have read always refers to a specific file name, but, when I submit that request, SF redirects it to /download, and something happens, but I don't get what I am looking for. Here is the current code:

```
$url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.3.6/OpenBLAS-0.3.6-x64.zip'
# $url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.3.6/OpenBLAS-0.3.6-x64.zip/download'
$output = 'C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-0.3.6-x64.zip'
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $output
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me in Windows 10 PowerShell 5.1.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $path -UserAgent [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::FireFox
```

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23fccc30-5f84-4a84-8160-c6e95102b11c/powershell-invokewebrequest-sourceforge-urlsredirectiondynamic-content?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: I don't see how to close a request, but this has been working for me for some time now:
$uri = 'https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/archive/v0.3.10.zip'
$output = 'C:\BLAS\v0.3.10.zip'
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.DownloadFile($uri,"$output")